# Salvar informações de um formulario

Tags: php, array, string

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de provas online conforme a imagem a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As questoes vem direto do banco de dados (MYSQL) e assim monto a prova exibindo questão por questão, quando o usuario marca a resposta e clica em "Próximo" avança para a próxima questão.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: como vou armazenar numa mesma variável, seja array ou qualquer coisa, todas as respostas da prova?

Este é o código do meu formulario:

```
<?php 

require_once('validasessao.php');
$codigo = $_GET['codigo'];

include_once("./classes/conexao.class.php");
include_once("./classes/avaliacoes.class.php");
include_once("./classes/QuestoesDisciplinas.class.php");

$conn               = new Conexao();
$questaoDisciplina  = new QuestoesDisciplinas($codigoDisciplina, $codigoQuestao);
$avaliacao          = new Avaliacoes($codigoAvaliacao, $codigoDisciplina, $dataAvaliacao, $horaInicioAvaliacao, $horaTerminoAvaliacao, $situacaoAvaliacao);

#localizar a avaliação
if($avaliacao->localizarAvaliacao($codigo)){

    #pegar os códigos
    $codigoAvaliacao        = $avaliacao->getCodigoAvaliacao();
    $codigoDisciplina       = $avaliacao->getCodigoDisciplina();

    #buscar as questões
    $res = $questaoDisciplina->buscarQuestoesDisciplina($codigoDisciplina);
    $array = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);   
    if($_POST['numeroQuestao'] == 0) {
        $numeroQuestao = 1;
    } else {
        $numeroQuestao = $_POST['numeroQuestao'];

        $respostaUsuario = $_POST['respostaUsuario'];   

        #$respostas[$numeroQuestao-1] = $respostaUsuario;

        #print_r($respostas);           
    }


    if($numeroQuestao <= $array['quantidadeQuestoesDisciplina']){


<form name = "prova" id = "prova" action = "?pag=provas-p.php&codigo=<?php echo $codigo ?>" method = "POST">
    <table>

        <tr>
            <td><b>Questao <?php echo $numeroQuestao . "/". $array['quantidadeQuestoesDisciplina'] ?></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $array['descricaoQuestao'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>A) <input type = "radio" name = "respostaUsuario" value = "A"><?php echo $array['descricaoResposta1Questao']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B) <input type = "radio" name = "respostaUsuario" value = "B"><?php echo $array['descricaoResposta2Questao']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C) <input type = "radio" name = "respostaUsuario" value = "C"><?php echo $array['descricaoResposta3Questao']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>D) <input type = "radio" name = "respostaUsuario" value = "D"><?php echo $array['descricaoResposta4Questao']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>E) <input type = "radio" name = "respostaUsuario" value = "E"><?php echo $array['descricaoResposta5Questao']?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><br></td>
        </tr>


        $numeroQuestao++;

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type = "hidden" name = "numeroQuestao" id = "numeroQuestao" value = "<?php echo $numeroQuestao ?>">
                <input type = "submit" name = "enviar" id = "enviar" value = "Próximo">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Quero apenas salvar a resposta do usuario, mas nao to conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes? Como funciona o seu formulário? Usa ajax ou recarrega a cada pergunta? E você quer guardar esses valores no servidor ou no cliente?

Comment: ao clicar em "proximo" ele recarrega a pagina com o formulario e salvo o valor da resposta que enviei por $_POST[], eu to tentando salvar num array com indices iguais ao numero de questoes e mesmo assim ele só ta salvando a ultima resposta

Comment: Se você está fazendo um post para cada vez que o 'Próximo' for clicado, então você ta chamando a página do action de novo, ele não vai manter os valores que estavam lá. Você pode colocar num array criado no escopo de `session` e no final usa o array para gravar as respostas no banco.

Mas coloque os códigos que você já fez para facilitar a nossa ajuda.

Comment: "Você pode colocar num array criado no escopo de session e no final usa o array para gravar as respostas no banco" - Como assim?

Comment: Faz o seguinte. Coloca todo o código que você tem dessa página na sua pergunta, mas não como print screen. Coloca como texto mesmo pra gente poder usar pra elabora uma resposta pra você.

Comment: Tá lá, editei e botei o código

Comment: O problema é armazenar as respostas anteriores, mas dou refresh na pagina a cada questao, entao como eu faria pra manter estes dados?

Comment: Invés de você usar uma array simples, como $respostas[], utilize um array de session, $_SESSION["respostas"][]... e você terá $_SESSION["respostas"][1] pra pergunta 1, $_SESSION["respostas"][2] e por aí vai.  Só lembre de iniciar a sessão na PRIMEIRA linha do php com session_start();

Answer (score 0):

Pelo include no arquivo `validasessao.php` lá em cima, assumo que você já tenha um sessão iniciada, se não, ponha um `session_start(); no início do código.

```
#localizar a avaliação
if($avaliacao->localizarAvaliacao($codigo)){

#pegar os códigos
$codigoAvaliacao        = $avaliacao->getCodigoAvaliacao();
$codigoDisciplina       = $avaliacao->getCodigoDisciplina();

#buscar as questões
$res = $questaoDisciplina->buscarQuestoesDisciplina($codigoDisciplina);
$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);   
if($_POST['numeroQuestao'] == 0) {
    $numeroQuestao = 1;
} else {
    $numeroQuestao = $_POST['numeroQuestao'];

    $respostaUsuario = $_POST['respostaUsuario'];   

    $_SESSION['respostas'][$numeroQuestao-1] = $respostaUsuario;

    print_r($_SESSION['respostas']);
}
```

Isso deve resolver o problema de você só estar conseguindo manter a última resposta.